# Unit tests for inherited behaviour in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, tdd

**Context**:  *I am following the Building Skills in Object-Oriented Design by Steven F. Lott. The goal is to experiment with various betting strategies for roulette -- by building a roulette simulation and a player for each strategy in question.*

I have a base class Player and several subclasses PlayerXY of Player which inherit behaviour.

```
e.g. by design, each roulette bet must be paid for when placed 
-- this is handled in the Player class and inherited by each PlayerXY subclass
```

**Question:** how do I unit-test this behaviour for the subclasses?

**Ideas**: I have outlined some ideas below.

**The dilemma:**

- I know I will be adding more PlayerXY classes, and I would like to be able to do so easily.
- I think *Idea 1* offers the most flexibility: if for whatever reason the behaviour of one of the classes needs to differ in the future, I can just rewrite that particular test (without affecting other classes!).
- However, with *Idea 1*, each time I add a new PlayerXY class, I need to copy-paste and edit more than 50 lines of code in the corresponding PlayerXYTest -- and I wonder if this can be avoided (without running into a huge nightmare in case one of the players needs to change in the future).

Comment: You don't. The inherited behaviour should be tested in the parent class.

Comment: In fact, I'd prefer to test this.. and I've seen many answers on SO where people encourage doing so.

Comment: Unless the parent class method is overridden, you should not test it in the child class. If you think the parent class method needs additional tests, you can add them with the tests of the parent (if you have access to it, which you have in this case.)

Comment: Ok, but how do I regression-ensure the child class has the desired behaviour then?

Comment: @stanl3y There are many answers on SO encouraging poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1:** put the test into an external module and then call it from each unit-test of PlayerXY

```
(player_common.py)

def test_placing_bet_reduces_stake(self, player):
  ...
  self.assertEqual(...)
```

and

```
import player_common

class Player17Test(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_placing_bet_reduces_stake(self):
      player = Player17()
      player_common.test_placing_bet_reduces_stake(self, player)
```

---

**Idea 2:** write the test for the base class Player and then inherit in the subclasses

```
class PlayerTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_placing_bet_reduces_stake(self):
    ...
```

and

```
class Player17Test(PlayerTest):
  ...
```

---

**Idea 3:** put the test into an external module and import it in each unit-test of PlayerXY

```
(player_common.py)

def test_placing_bet_reduces_stake(self):
  ...
  self.assertEqual(...)
```

and

```
class Player17Test(unittest.TestCase):

  from player_common import test_placing_bet_reduces_stake
```

---